# How to loop through nested arrays in React Native

Tags: api, loops, react-native

I have an API which has nested objects, and within that nested arrays.  I have managed to display some data on the screen with .map, i have hard coded the first row.  How to a do a nested map in React Native?

I have tried various solutions on stackoverflow but so far have not found any that have matched my solution

This is an example of my API and Code

```
{  
   "Name":"Worcestershire Acute Hospitals",
   "Sites":[  
      {  
         "SiteCode":"ALX",
         "Statistics":[  
            {  
               "Id":3,
               "Name":"Last Updated",
               "Value":"29 Jul 2019 18:26:39:487",
               "LastUpdated":"2019-07-29T18:32:16.833",
               "ImageURL":"Ambulance"
            },
            {  
               "Id":4,
               "Name":"Safety Level",
               "Value":"Overwhelmed",
               "LastUpdated":"2019-07-29T18:32:16.833",
               "ImageURL":"Ambulance"
            },
            {  
               "Id":5,
               "Name":"Todays Admissions",
               "Value":"32",
               "LastUpdated":"2019-07-29T18:32:16.833",
               "ImageURL":"Ambulance"
            },


  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://ralxwebdev01/tod/api/tod')
.then(response => this.setState({ WrhDatas: response.data.Sites[0].Statistics }));
  }

  renderWrhName() {
    return this.state.WrhDatas.map(wrh => <Text key={wrh.Id}>{wrh.Name}</Text>);
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.WrhDatas);
    return (
      <View>
      <Text>
      {this.renderWrhName()}
      </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I know for sites i am using [0] and the data displays on the screen.  But I want to loop through sites, then loop through statistics.

Answer (score 0):

*I want to loop through sites, then loop through statistics.*

In `componentDidMount` you can do this,

```
this.setState({ WrhDatas: data.Sites.map(data => data.Statistics.map(stat=> stat)) },()=>console.log(this.state.WrhDatas));
```

This will return you the `Array of Array's`.

And your `renderWrhName` function should be,

```
renderWrhName() {
    return this.state.WrhDatas.map(wrh => wrh.map(wrh => <div key={wrh.Id}>{wrh.Name}</div>));
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cyftei). (Tested with sample data provided in post)

**Note:** For simplicity I have used `div` to render the data, but the same will work for `Text`.